# Attempting to dynamically determine marker image based on different database queries

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using v3 of the google map api, I have a view of the US. I have markers set at locations that are converted to lat and lng from 2 address queries in my pg database. I am trying to differentiate which marker image appears based on which query result the address is from. I have successfully created 2 objects based on these queries and they are logged separately, however, I am unable to use the source of these objects to determine which markers are displayed.

```
var labels = '';
var iconBase = 'green.png';
var iconBaseRed = 'red.png';

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
var arr = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
console.log(xhr.responseText);
if(Array.isArray(arr)){
showMarkers(arr);
}
}
}
xhr.open('GET', 'markers.php', true);
xhr.send();

function showMarkers(locations){
var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
return new google.maps.Marker({
position: location,
icon: iconBase,
label: labels[i % labels.length]
});
});

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
        {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
  }


var xhrred = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhrred.onreadystatechange = function() {

if (xhrred.readyState == 4) {
var arrred = JSON.parse(xhrred.responseText);
console.log(xhrred.responseText);
if(Array.isArray(arrred)){
showMarkers(arrred);
}
}
}
xhrred.open('GET', 'markersred.php', true);
xhrred.send();


function showMarkers(locations){
var markersRed = locations.map(function(locationred, i) {
return new google.maps.Marker({
position: locationred,
icon: iconBaseRed,
label: labels[i % labels.length]
});
});

var markerClusterRed = new MarkerClusterer(map, markersRed,
        {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});

  }
```

I had the approach of setting seperate variables for each XMLHttpRequest, this is how I was able to create multiple JSON objects. I then tried to do the same with the showMarker function, but it does not work. Herein lies my problem... Any help is appreciated.

Here is a link to the test (see console log for data) 
[www.rightmediasolutions.com/gs_chrome/testing.html](http://www.rightmediasolutions.com/gs_chrome/testing.html)

You will notice it only displays iconBaseRed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are making two different ajax calls, and each of them returns an array of locations. Now you want to display a different marker icon depending on which ajax call are you drawing from.

I'd pass the marker icon as a parameter to the function:

```
function showMarkers(locations, theIcon){
    var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
        return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            icon: theIcon,
            label: labels[i % labels.length]
    });
});
```

Then have each ajax result call `showMarkers` with its own icon:

```
showMarkers(arr, iconBase);
showMarkers(arrred, iconBaseRed);
```